# How to implement DI by using Castle Windsor in Nancy Self Hosted Project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, nancy

I'm developing web application with Nancy framework. 
In Console Application (background service/daemon) I use Castle Windsor DI container and use the next initialization code:

```
_container = new WindsorContainer ();
_container.Register (Component.For (typeof(IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy (typeof(Repository<>)).LifeStyle.Transient);
_container.Register (Component.For<ILog> ().ImplementedBy<FileConsoleLog> ());
```

But I didn't know how to rewrite this code with using TinyIOC. I try to use WindsorNancyBootstrapper DI implementation. In this way I catch next problem. How i can rewrite this?

```
   protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer (container);

        container.Register<IEnumerable<ISuperSimpleViewEngineMatcher>> ((c, p) => {
            return new List<ISuperSimpleViewEngineMatcher> () 
            { 
                new StringTranslateTokenMatcher () 
            };
        });
    }
```

How I can rewrite first or second code, using one of the DI containers?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You install the Nancy Windsor Bootstrapper NuGet package:

```
Install-Package Nancy.Bootstrappers.Windsor
```

Then you create a `Bootstrapper` which inherits from `WindsorNancyBootstrapper`, and do your Windsor configuration there:

```
public class Bootstrapper : WindsorNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>)).LifeStyle.Transient);
       _container.Register(Component.For<ILog>().ImplementedBy<FileConsoleLog>());
    }
}
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy.Bootstrappers.Windsor#usage) for more info.

Comment: Yes, I already did it. I need to rewrite second block of code for Windsor.

Comment: Excuse me, you didn't understand me. But I resolved this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The next code was added.

```
protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(
            Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.NancyContext context)
        {
            base.ConfigureRequestContainer (container, context);
            container.Register<IUserMapper, SiteUserMapper> ();

            container.Register (typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>)).AsMultiInstance ();
            container.Register (typeof(ILog), typeof(DatabaseLog));
            container.Register (typeof(IServiceGeo), typeof(ServiceGeo));
            container.Register (typeof(IServiceUser), typeof(ServiceUser));
        }
```

TinyIoc can register generic

```
 container.Register (typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>)).AsMultiInstance ();
```